# Angular Material datepicker Hijri date bug

Tags: angular, date, angular-material, datepicker, hijri

When using the "ar-SA" locale in Angular Material datepicker component, the date on display (illustrated in the following image) is shifted back two months and does not represent the actual date.

[Image of incorrect month being displayed in date picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqP5o.png)

Moreover, when selecting the date on the datepicker, another date appears different to that selected (indicated in image below); however, the date that appears in the text field is the correct date that matches today's date.
[Image of different date picker input value and text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4s5g.png)

**Diagnosis steps:**

1. According to
   (https://github.com/angular/components/issues/27429), the issue
   occurs because the Angular Material Native date adapter (which
   extends Date JS), doesn't support Hijri date.
2. I have used the Hijri date adapter in
   ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter
   (https://github.com/Ebrahiem-Gamal-Mohamed/ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter/tree/main/projects/ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter),
   and it works flawlessly, but my main issue is that I want the user
   to switch between locales (gregorian/hijri) seemlessly. The
   ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter doesn't support Gregorian.
3. Suggested solution is either to use a date adapter that switches
   between the native date adapter and
   ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter, or extend the
   ngx-angular-material-hijri-adapter to allow overriding the Hijri
   functions when a gregorian locale is passed.

**Reproduction**
StackBlitz link: https://components-issue-f7fmes.stackblitz.io
Steps to reproduce:
Select an Today's date
Date in text field appears correct
Date in Date picker appears incorrectly

**Expected Behavior**
Date should match in both picker and text field

**Actual Behavior**
Date in datepicker is incorrect and should be shifted

**Environment**
Angular: 15.2.9
CDK/Material:15.2.1
Browser(s): Google Chrome
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Windows 11